# Rudin, Definition of lower/upper semicontinous, understanding the consequences.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

In Rudin (real and complex analysis) page 37 there's the following definition

> Let $f$ be a real (or extended-real) function on a topological space.
>   If $$ \left\{x \;:\; f(x) > \alpha \right\} $$ is open for every real
>   $\alpha$, $f$ is said to be lower semicontinuous. If $$ \left\{x \;:\;
> > f(x) < \alpha \right\} $$ is open for every real $\alpha$, $f$ is said
>   to be upper semicontinuous.

Right after this definition is stated that the following property is an almost immediate consequence of such definition

> *The supremum of any collection of lower semicontinous functions is
>   lower semicontinuous. The infimum of any collection of upper
>   semicontinuous functions is upper semicontinuous.*

Why is this true?

Let's take a family $\left\{f_j(x)\right\}_{j \in J}$ of lower semicontinuous functions, let

$$
f(x) = \sup_{j} f_j(x)
$$
let also $\alpha$ be a real number, why is the set

$$
\left\{x \;:\; f(x) > \alpha \right\}
$$

open?

Comment: Write the set as a countable union of open sets.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the set $\{x : f_j(x) > \alpha\}$ to be the pre-image of an open interval: $f_j^{-1}[(\alpha,\infty)]$, which is open by semicontinuity, and the union of open sets is open. Furthermore, we have

$$\bigcup_{j\in J} f^{-1}_j [(\alpha,\infty)] = f^{-1}[(\alpha,\infty)].$$

To show this, first let $x \in f^{-1}[(\alpha,\infty)]$. We know $f(x) > \alpha$, but we need to show that $\alpha < f_{j_0}(x) \le f(x)$ for some $j_0 \in J$. Since $f(x) = \sup_j f_j(x)$, the $f_j(x)$ must approach $f(x)$ to within any $\varepsilon > 0$. In particular, take $\varepsilon < f(x) - \alpha$, then for some $j_0 \in J$,

$$f(x) - f_{j_0}(x) < \varepsilon < f(x) - \alpha$$

which implies $\alpha < f_{j_0}(x)$ as required after subracting $f(x)$ on both ends and reversing signs.

For the reverse, take $x \in \bigcup_j f_j^{-1}[(\alpha,\infty)]$. Then $x$ is in any particular $j_0 \in J$, which means $f_{j_0}(x) > \alpha$. Now since $f(x) = \sup_j f_j(x)$, we have  $f(x) \ge f_{j_0}(x) > \alpha$. Thus, $x \in f^{-1}[(\alpha,\infty)]$.

Therefore, $\{x : f(x) > \alpha\}$ is open since it is a union of open sets.